# If function fails in loading buttons based on the condition

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The if function inside the function *openwin(),* fails to load the buttons based on the value returned by the function *update_room_menu* inside the *class App.*

Irrespective of the selection inside *update_room*_*menu,* the if function inside *open_win,* returns the same values.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from tkinter import *
import fitz
from termcolor import colored
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter 
import os
from PIL import Image

def open_win():
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.geometry("950x400")
    window.title("Rooms list")
    for i in range(15):
        window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=5)
        window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=5)
    
    if app.update_room_menu("B1"):
        #Row 1
        button1 = tk.Button(window, text="FWT BA 001", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda: app.handle_submit(button1.cget('text')))
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        button2 = tk.Button(window, text="FWT BA 002", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10, command =lambda: app.handle_submit(button2.cget('text')))
        button2.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10, pady=10)
        button3 = tk.Button(window, text="RAMP BA 003", font='arial 8',padx = 10,pady=10,command=lambda:app.buttohandle_submit(button3.cget('text')))
        button3.grid(row =1, column=3,padx=10, pady=10)
        button4 = tk.Button(window, text="MECH WATER TANK(WATER FEATURE 13) BA 004",font='arial 8',padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button4.cget('text')))
        button4.grid(row=1, column=4,padx=10,pady=10)

    elif app.update_room_menu("B2"):
        buttona = tk.Button(window, text ="MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 051", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(buttona.cget('text')))
        buttona.grid(row=1, column = 1,padx=10,pady=10)
        buttonb = tk.Button(window, text ="PEA BA 052", font = "arial 8", padx=10,pady=10,command = lambda:app.handle_submit(buttonb.cget('text')))
        buttonb.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10,pady=10)
        buttonc = tk.Button(window, text="UNIFORM ISSUE BA 054", font="arial 8", padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(buttonc.cget('text')))
        buttonc.grid(row=1, column=3,padx=10,pady=10)
        buttond = tk.Button(window, text="CMA BA 055", font='arial 8',padx=10,pady=10 ,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(buttond.cget('text')))
        buttond.grid(row=1, column=4,padx=10,pady=10)

       
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("300x150")
        self.master.title("Document Finder")

        # Create dropdown menus
        self.location_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.location_var.set("Select the Plot")
        self.location_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.location_var, "PA", "PB",command = self.update_sub_area_menu)
        self.location_dropdown.pack()
        
        self.sub_area_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.sub_area_var.set("Select the sub-area")
        self.sub_area_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.sub_area_var,"",command = self.update_level_menu)
        self.sub_area_dropdown.pack()

        self.level_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.level_var.set("Select a level")
        self.level_dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(self.master, self.level_var,"",command=self.update_room_menu)
        self.level_dropdown.pack()

        # Create button to search for document
        self.search_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Submit", command=open_win)
        self.search_button.pack()

    def update_sub_area_menu(self,selection):
        if selection == "PA":
            sub_areas = ["Basement A", "Club Lounge", "Hotel-Luxury", "Hotel-Service Apartments", "Hotel-Ultra Luxury", "Link Levels", "Others", "Penthouses", "Podium A", "Rental Offices", "Restaurants", "Spa/Gym"]
        elif selection == "PB":
            sub_areas = ["Apartments-Duplex", "Apartments-Simplex", "Basement B", "Link", "Mech & Roof", "Podium B"]
        else:
            sub_areas = []
        self.sub_area_var.set("Select the sub-area")
        self.sub_area_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        for sub_area in sub_areas:
            self.sub_area_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=sub_area, command=tk._setit(self.sub_area_var,sub_area,self.update_level_menu))
    
    def update_level_menu(self, selection):
        if selection == "Basement A":
            levels = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"]
        elif selection == "Club Lounge":
            levels = ["53F"]
        else:
            levels = []
        self.level_var.set("Select a level")
        self.level_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        for level in levels:
            self.level_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=level, command=tk._setit(self.level_var, level, self.update_room_menu))
    
    def update_room_menu(self, selection):
        if selection == "B1":
            return "B1"
        elif selection == "B2":
            return "B2"
        self.rooms_var.set("Select a room")

    
    
    def open_win(self, window):
        window = tk.Toplevel()
        window.geometry("950x400")
        window.title("Rooms list")
        for i in range(15):
            window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=5)
            window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=5)
    
        if app.update_room_menu("B1"):
            #Row 1
            button1 = tk.Button(window, text="FWT BA 001", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda: app.handle_submit(button1.cget('text')))
            button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
            button2 = tk.Button(window, text="FWT BA 002", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10, command =lambda: app.handle_submit(button2.cget('text')))
            button2.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10, pady=10)
            button3 = tk.Button(window, text="RAMP BA 003", font='arial 8',padx = 10,pady=10,command=lambda:app.buttohandle_submit(button3.cget('text')))
            button3.grid(row =1, column=3,padx=10, pady=10)
            button4 = tk.Button(window, text="MECH WATER TANK(WATER FEATURE 13) BA 004",font='arial 8',padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button4.cget('text')))
            button4.grid(row=1, column=4,padx=10,pady=10)

        elif app.update_room_menu("B2"):
            buttona = tk.Button(window, text ="MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 051", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button37.cget('text')))
            buttona.grid(row=1, column = 1,padx=10,pady=10)
            buttonb = tk.Button(window, text ="PEA BA 052", font = "arial 8", padx=10,pady=10,command = lambda:app.handle_submit(button38.cget('text')))
            buttonb.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10,pady=10)
            buttonc = tk.Button(window, text="UNIFORM ISSUE BA 054", font="arial 8", padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button39.cget('text')))
            buttonc.grid(row=1, column=3,padx=10,pady=10)
            buttond = tk.Button(window, text="CMA BA 055", font='arial 8',padx=10,pady=10 ,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button40.cget('text')))
            buttond.grid(row=1, column=4,padx=10,pady=10)

    def find_document(self):
        # Construct the file path based on the selected room and level
        file_path = f"C:/Users/user/stuff/drawinglochighlighter/dropdown/OT31317-ZP0100-DWG-{self.location_var.get()}-{self.level_var.get()}.pdf"
        # Check if the file exists in the directory
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
        # Open the file using PyMuPDF
            return fitz.open(file_path)
    
        #Function to highlight text in PDF
    def highlight_text(self, pdf_file, room_type):
        for page in pdf_file:
            ### SEARCH
            text = str(room_type)
            print(text)
            split_text = text.split()
            word = " ".join(split_text[-2:])
            print(word)
            text_instances = page.search_for(word)

            ### HIGHLIGHT
            for inst in text_instances:
                highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
                highlight.set_colors({"stroke":(0, 1, 0), "thickness": 5})  # <-- change thickness here
                highlight.update()
             
                # Add a yellow circle with desired opacity on top of the green rectangle
                circle_center = fitz.Point((inst.tl.x + inst.br.x)/2, (inst.tl.y + inst.br.y)/2)
                circle_width = 300
                circle_height = 150
                circle_bbox = fitz.Rect(circle_center.x - circle_width/2, circle_center.y - circle_height/2,
                             circle_center.x + circle_width/2, circle_center.y + circle_height/2)
                circle_annot = page.add_circle_annot(circle_bbox)
                circle_annot.set_colors(stroke=(1,0,0), fill=None)
                circle_annot.set_border(width=10)
                circle_annot.set_opacity(0.7)
                circle_annot.border_width = 10
                circle_annot.update()

                print(highlight)  
                #print(yellow_rect)
                print(circle_annot)
                #print(rect)

    
            ### OUTPUT
            output_file_name = f"{room_type}.pdf" # generate a filename with only the room type
            pdf_file.save(output_file_name, garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)
    

    def handle_submit(self,room_type):
    
        pdf_file = self.find_document()
        if pdf_file:
            self.highlight_text(pdf_file, room_type)
            messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Text highlighted in PDF!")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error","PDF File not found for selected space ID")


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The if function inside the function open_win()*,* fails to load the buttons based on the value returned by the function update_room_menu() inside the *class App.*

Irrespective of the selection inside update_room_menu() *,* the 'if' function inside open_win()*,* returns the same values, ie, if I select B1 in the dropdown, or B2, I get only the buttons of B1.

Comment: `app.update_room_menu("B1")` always returns a true value, so you will never take the `elif` clause.   I assume you actually wanted to read the "B1" vs "B2" value from a control somewhere, because what you have will always take the "B1" path.

Comment: Change the ```open_win()``` into a method of the ```App```, and use ```self.level_var.get()``` to get the current value of the ```OptionMenu```.

Comment: @relent95 can you please elaborate? or help me with a code?

Comment: Do it by yourself. It's pretty simple if you understand the class and method.

Comment: @relent95, I am really sorry, I will need your help.

Comment: I have updated the code, it include the function handle_submit() also.

Comment: If you select B1, or B2, you are getting the same results right? The code is working, the problem is with the if condition inside open_win().

Comment: From the dropdown, "Select a level".                

The if function inside the function openwin(), fails to load the buttons based on the value returned by the function update_room_menu inside the class App.

Irrespective of the selection inside update_room_menu, the if function inside open_win, returns the same values.

Comment: Use the updated code. But, have you observed how the if condition fails?

Answer (score 0):

Change the open_win() into a method of the App, and use self.level_var.get() to get the current value of the OptionMenu.

````
    def update_level_menu(self, selection):
        if selection == "Basement A":
            levels = ["B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7"]
        elif selection == "Club Lounge":
            levels = ["53F"]
        else:
            levels = []
        self.level_var.set("Select a level")
        self.level_dropdown['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
        for level in levels:
            self.level_dropdown['menu'].add_command(label=level, command=tk._setit(self.level_var, level, self.open_win))
    

    

    def open_win(self, window):
        window = tk.Toplevel()
        window.geometry("950x400")
        window.title("Rooms list")
        for i in range(15):
            window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=5)
            window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=5)

        
        if self.level_var.get() == "B1":
            #Row 1
            button1 = tk.Button(window, text="FWT BA 001", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda: app.handle_submit(button1.cget('text')))
            button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
            button2 = tk.Button(window, text="FWT BA 002", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10, command =lambda: app.handle_submit(button2.cget('text')))
            button2.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10, pady=10)
            button3 = tk.Button(window, text="RAMP BA 003", font='arial 8',padx = 10,pady=10,command=lambda:app.buttohandle_submit(button3.cget('text')))
            button3.grid(row =1, column=3,padx=10, pady=10)
            button4 = tk.Button(window, text="MECH WATER TANK(WATER FEATURE 13) BA 004",font='arial 8',padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button4.cget('text')))
            button4.grid(row=1, column=4,padx=10,pady=10)

        elif self.level_var.get() == "B2" :
            buttona = tk.Button(window, text ="MECH (FAN ROOM) BA 051", font='arial 8', padx=10, pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button37.cget('text')))
            buttona.grid(row=1, column = 1,padx=10,pady=10)
            buttonb = tk.Button(window, text ="PEA BA 052", font = "arial 8", padx=10,pady=10,command = lambda:app.handle_submit(button38.cget('text')))
            buttonb.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10,pady=10)
            buttonc = tk.Button(window, text="UNIFORM ISSUE BA 054", font="arial 8", padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button39.cget('text')))
            buttonc.grid(row=1, column=3,padx=10,pady=10)
            buttond = tk.Button(window, text="CMA BA 055", font='arial 8',padx=10,pady=10 ,command=lambda:app.handle_submit(button40.cget('text')))
            buttond.grid(row=1, column=4,padx=10,pady=10) ```
````